# Two way binding of IsChecked within a nested MenuItem

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate, menuitem

I have a nested context menu like this:

```
<ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <MenuItem Header="Thing Count" ItemsSource="{Binding ThingsProvider}">
```

NB the Thing Count parent MenuItem with children from ThingsProvider.

ThingsProvider provides a List of ThingViewModel which contains properties Thing and IsChecked. I want to be able to control IsChecked from my main view model and from the user via the MenuItem but I have hit a problem; If I use an ItemContainerStyle like this.

```
    <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=Thing, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding Path=IsChecked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </Style>
    </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
```

then (predictably I suppose as it's a style) it will observe the ViewModel's IsChecked but will not set it.

If I use an ItemTemplate like so

```
<MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Thing, Mode=OneWay}"/>
  </DataTemplate>
 </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
```

I can't get to the MenuItem's IsChecked property as I've only got the TextBlock. If I put a MenuItem in the ItemTemplate then I end up with nested MenuItems in my UI and it looks bad.

There must be a way to do this but I'm stumped at the moment, can anyone help?

Cheers

Rich

Comment: Are you calling the PropertyChanged event on the property setter? I also believe you want the mode TwoWay.

Comment: Yes @romerotg, my VM implements INotifyPropertyChanged and I am firing on the setter. I have OneWay binding on the Text as the property Thing never changes (has a private setter). I want some way of being able to bind the MenuItem's IsChecked property to IsChecked on my viewmodel but don't know how to do it within the DataTemplate.